# Issues Displaying SSIS Data - Importing from Excel File to SQL DB

Tags: excel, ssis, integration-testing

I am importing data from an Excel file into a SQL DB but it keeps giving me errors. I receive the error listed below for all of my control flows and there are five. How can I resolve this error?

> Data viewer at path 'Excel Source Output' of task 'Data Flow Task - Course Facts' [DataflowID: {DF84ABE7-A1C5-4CA8-B5B9-C4FED8744F8E}; IDString: Paths[Excel Source.Excel Source Output]; PackageRPath: Integration Services Project1\Package.dtsx];;;break always (currently 0)

event log

[image]

Comment: Hi @T.com, please add more details - full error message + print screen, etc.

Comment: We are going to need more information in order to help you